# Bootstrap 4 collapsed navbar loses navbar-brand

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, navbar

I'm trying to style a Bootstrap 4 navbar that retains the navbar-brand without it disappearing when collapsed.

Here's my code:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exCollapsingNavbar2" aria-controls="exCollapsingNavbar2" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    &#9776;
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-xs" id="exCollapsingNavbar2">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Responsive navbar</a>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

So just to be clear, the nav-items and navbar-brand disappear when the navbar is collapsed, and I'd like the navbar-brand to still be visible.

The only CSS I can think of is to use display, but that's not having any effect.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 3):

You should change your HTML markup and make sure that the `.nav-brand` is outside the `<div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-xs" id="exCollapsingNavbar2">`:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exCollapsingNavbar2" aria-controls="exCollapsingNavbar2" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    &#9776;
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Responsive navbar</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-xs" id="exCollapsingNavbar2">
  ....
```

Now your navbar should look like that shown in the following figure in the small viewports:
[image: navbar on small viewports]

You possible also want to add the `pull-xs-right` class to the "hamburger" button:

```
<button class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up pull-xs-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exCollapsingNavbar2" aria-controls="exCollapsingNavbar2" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
```

Then it should look like that shown beneath:

[image]

When you click the button, the first link still floats next to the `.nav-brand`:

[image]

Use the following SCSS code to remove the `float-left` from the `.nav-brand` for the extra small viewport:

```
.navbar {
  @include media-breakpoint-down(xs) {
    .navbar-brand {
      float: none;
    }
  }
}
```

The SCSS code above compiles into CSS code as follows:

```
@media (max-width: 543px) {
  .navbar .navbar-brand {
    float: none; 
  } 
}
```

More information about Bootstrap 4's responsive navbars can also be found at: http://bassjobsen.weblogs.fm/bootstrap-4s-responsive-navbars/